# Multilabel text classification with BERT and highly imbalanced training data

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, loss-function, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to train a multilabel text classification model using BERT. Each piece of text can belong to 0 or more of a total of 485 classes. My model consists of a dropout layer and a linear layer added on top of the pooled output from the [bert-base-uncased](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased) model from Hugging Face. The loss function I'm using is the [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) in PyTorch.

I have millions of labeled observations to train on. But the training data are highly unbalanced, with some labels appearing in less than 10 observations and others appearing in more than 100K observations! I'd like to get a "good" recall.

My first attempt at training without adjusting for data imbalance produced a [micro recall rate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification) of 70% (good enough) but a [macro recall rate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification) of 45% (not good enough). These numbers indicate that the model isn't performing well on underrepresented classes.

How can I effectively adjust for the data imbalance during training to improve the macro recall rate? I see we can provide label weights to BCEWithLogitsLoss loss function. But given the very high imbalance in my data leading to weights in the range of 1 to 1M, can I actually get the model to converge? My initial experiments show that a weighted loss function is going up and down during training.

Alternatively, is there a better approach than using BERT + dropout + linear layer for this type of task?

Answer (score 2):

In your case it might be helpful to balance the labels in the training data. You have a lot of data, so you could afford to loose a part of it by balancing. But before you do this, I recommend to read [this answer about balancing classes in traing data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/270277/367429).

If you really only care about recall, you could try to tune your model maximizing recall.